# SpringBoot can't start when assign profile

Tags: spring-boot

I want configure yaml profiles in spring application.  but when I add spring.profiles.active in application.yml, the App does not start. no any debug point and error

Here is application.yml file:
[image]

see image[image]

Comment: When I delete spring.profiles.active=test, Application can start..

Comment: I think this is off-topic and should be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)